# Taylor polynomials of $\sin(x)$ are, for $x > 0,$ alternatively upper resp. lower bounds?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, taylor-expansion, upper-lower-bounds

For $x > 0$, I observed:

- $\sin(x) < x$
- $\sin(x) > x - x^3 \mathbin{/} 3!$
- $\sin(x) < x - x^3 \mathbin{/} 3! + x^5 \mathbin{/} 5!$
- etc.

Is it true that the Taylor polynomials of $\sin(x)$ are, for $x > 0$, alternatively upper resp. lower bounds? If yes, how to prove it?

Comment: How do you get the polynomial terms of the sine to begin with?

Comment: I think your inequalities are all true only  for $x\in(0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah  If you plot those functions, you will see that the inequalities are very likely to hold for $x > 0$. But what is your argument? Do you have a proof? Or a counterexample?

Comment: @imranfat Truncated tailor series, expanded around zero. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_series

Comment: Well, then you know it's an alternating series. Now what do you know about error bounds for an alternating series?

Comment: @imranfat I know nothing about the sign of the error. You seem to have an easy answer, just tell me, please.

Comment: For an alternating series, the maximum error is bounded by the first term you ignored. This is only true for alternating series. That explains what you are asserting in the title. One thing though,  the Taylor series of the sine is all real numbers. You can mimic the sine curve by the Taylor series at any x if you take sufficient number of terms. I would actually advise you to read about properties of alternating series.

Comment: @imranfat What you say seems very likely, indeed. Thank you for the advice, you are right, I should read more about it, but it was precisely my question: Where do I find a proof? Perhaps you can give me a reference (preferably online)? I could not find any, because search results are "polluted" with general introductions to power series.

Comment: @imranfat I finally found a reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test (also known as Leibniz criterion). I believe that, for $x$ strictly positive and small enough, it proves my claim, indeed. But for any strictly positive $x$, some more work is required.